# MySQL optimize database - data integrity

Tags: mysql

when doing MySQL INNODB's optimize command with this code:

mysqlcheck -uroot -p --optimize --databases database_name_here

i saw that innodb instead will drop the table - recreate it and then optimize it.

my question is, this action would create an exact table copy right?

for example, i have my fist column set to auto increment, and i have this:

```
______________________
| id | fname | lname |
----------------------
| 1  | abcd  | efgh  |
----------------------
| 2  | ijkl  | mnop  |
----------------------
| 4  | qrst  | uvwx  |
----------------------
```

after optimizing my innodb database, it wouldnt be like the table below even if the first column is auto increment right?

```
______________________
| id | fname | lname |
----------------------
| 1  | abcd  | efgh  |
----------------------
| 2  | ijkl  | mnop  |
----------------------
| 3  | qrst  | uvwx  |
----------------------
```

kindly confirm, i need this.

Comment: Optimize is not going to change the values in the columns, especially the primary key column.  This could be referred to by other tables and that would render the optimize functionality useless in most cases.

Comment: thanks men! hope you put that on the answer field so that i can mark it. take care!